# Setting up postfix

Tags: 14.04, server, email, postfix

I am trying to setup mail server on my Amazon EC2 following [this guide](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/).

But when I came by step 12, I ran into a problem, that it does not seems to have `250-mail.domain.com` in the `ehlo`-result? Which seems to be the mission on the guide.

I am not quite sure what informations to post, so let me know if you need some of my config files or anything.

Here is what I got:

```
$ telnet mail.domain.com smtp
Trying 12.345.67.890...
Connected to mail.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 domain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo mail.domain.com
250-domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
ehlo mail.domain.com 587
250-domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Note: The IP `12.345.67.890` is changed due to my privacy, and so is `domain.com` and `mail.domain.com`.